# MISRA C compliance for arithmetic addition

Tags: c, misra

Given the variables `a`, `b`, and `c`:

```
uint32_t a;
uint16_t b, c;
```

According to MISRA-C 2012 standard, the expression `a+b+c` is compliant whereas `b+c+a` is not compliant.

Why?

Comment: Honestly, this question is way too cryptic...

Comment: sorry the question should be U32a+u16b+u16c being compliant on MISRA-C vs U16a+u16b+u32c being non compliant.

Comment: @ramsurada What is "MISRA C"?  What are "u32a", "u16c", "u16c"?  (I know the answers, but it's not obvious to most members of this site I'd bet.)

Comment: @Tavian MISRA-C is a coding standard framework for developers to provide evidence of awareness and/or avoidance of C language constructs that lead to behavior which is *not* guaranteed by the standard(s) (i.e. undefined, unspecified, and implementation specific behavior). This also applies to well-defined C language constructs  shown (over many years of practice) to lead to (or strongly hint of) unintended behavior. See misra-c.com

Comment: Quote the rule number.

Answer (score 3):

With `u16a+u16b+u32c`, `u16a+u16b` is `unsigned` (think 16-bit) addition with potential overflow being lost prior to  subsequent addition to `u32c`.

`u32a+u16b+u16c` adds `u32a+u16b` and then uses this 32-bit result when adding `16c` preventing this loss.

Example

```
0x8000 + 0x8000 + 0x10000 
(0x8000 + 0x8000) + 0x10000 
0 + 0x10000 
0x10000
```

vs.

```
0x10000 + 0x8000 + 0x8000
(0x10000 + 0x8000) + 0x8000
0x18000 + 0x8000
0x20000
```

Answer (score 3):

Since C permits assignments between different arithmetic types to be performed automatically, the use of these implicit conversions can lead to unintended results, with the potential for loss of value, sign or precision. MISRA_C:2012 enforces strong typing via its "essential type" model to help warn when this might occur - known as the 10.x rules.

In this case there is a potential for overflow loss with `u16a+u16b+u32c`

Specifically this is a violation MISRA C:2012 Rule-10.7:  "If a composite expression is used as one operand of an operator in which the usual arithmetic conversions are performed then the other operand shall not have wider essential type”.

Its a common mistake to assume evaluation is influenced by the wider type. The type of the expression is actually determined by the type of its operands after any integral promotion.  You can remedy this by casting to the wider type, or rearrange the operands at the beginning of the expression as you’ve shown in your first example: `u32a+u16b+u16c`

Note: this does not imply that all operands in an expression are of the same essential type. The expression u32a + u16b + u16c is compliant as both additions will notionally be performed in type uint32_t.

Comment: Thanks a lot Chux,rici and Veriloud. I understood now.